# How should I use features when iterating a feature class with a cursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm iterating through all the features of a feature class (polygons) and I don't think I understand very well what each row is exactly. See example below of what I'm trying to do with arcpy:

```
DSM_model = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Data4Optimimty\ESRI_UK_Bluesky_DSM\ESRI_UK_Bluesky_DSM.gdb', 'DSM_25cm_2015')
fc_London_Bldngs_DSM = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Optimity_Temp.gdb', 'London_Bldngs_DSM')
field_names = ['OBJECTID']

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_London_Bldngs_DSM, field_names) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        DSM_bldng = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Optimity_Temp.gdb', 'DSM_bldng')
        temp = ExtractByMask (DSM_model, row)
        temp.save(DSM_bldng)
```

I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ESRI\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Arcpy_Scripts\Find_Flat_Roofs.py", line 44, in <module>
    temp = ExtractByMask (DSM_model, row)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 7249, in ExtractByMask
    in_mask_data)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 7245, in Wrapper
    out_raster)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 506, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
 Failed to execute (FindFlatRoofs).
```

I believe the second parameter of 'ExtractByMask' is expecting a feature layer, but I don't know what 'row' is.

Answer (score 4):

row is a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) with the value of OBJECTID in it, for example `(123,)`. To access the objectid use `row[0]`.

You can create a feature layer for each objectid and use in ExtractByMask. You can use the objectid token `OID@` instead of the name, since the name will be different for different inputs (shape, features in a geodatabase etc) but the token will Always work. SQL Query is constructed using format, arcpy.Describe and the object id value.

From what I can see you will overwrite each output since you name them the same so I have added objectid to the output names.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

DSM_model = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Data4Optimimty\ESRI_UK_Bluesky_DSM\ESRI_UK_Bluesky_DSM.gdb', 'DSM_25cm_2015')
fc_London_Bldngs_DSM = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Optimity_Temp.gdb', 'London_Bldngs_DSM')

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_London_Bldngs_DSM, 'OID@') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        DSM_bldng = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Optimity_Temp.gdb', 'DSM_bldng')
        sql = """{0}={1}""".format(arcpy.Describe(fc_London_Bldngs_DSM).OIDFieldName,row[0])
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc_London_Bldngs_DSM, out_layer='templyr', 
                                         where_clause=sql)

        temp = ExtractByMask(DSM_model, 'templyr')
        temp.save(DSM_bldng+str(row[0]))
```